# How to remove or dequeue google fonts in wordpress twentyfifteen

Tags: wordpress

I have created a child theme of twenty fifteen.  I'd like to remove the google fonts loaded in wp_head but I can't get it to work.  What is loaded is:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='twentyfifteen-fonts-css'  href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans%3A400italic%2C700italic%2C400%2C700%7CNoto+Serif%3A400italic%2C700italic%2C400%2C700%7CInconsolata%3A400%2C700&#038;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

I've created a function.php in my child theme but I can't figure out how to remove this.  I've gotten other things remove using:

```
remove_action('wp_head', '...');
```

But I can't figure out how to remove the fonts.

Also, any tips on how to remove the IE condition statements and css would be very helpful!

Thanks!

Comment: maybe this will help you https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-remove-an-action-via-functionsphp-in-a-child-theme

Answer (score 16, accepted):

TwentyFifteen uses a custom function to build a Google fonts URL which is then used with `wp_enqueue_style()`. To remove Google fonts create a function in your child theme to dequeue the stylesheet.

Use the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook and make sure to give it a higher priority than the hook in the parent theme. The default is 10 so in my example I use 20.

Example:

```
function wpse_dequeue_google_fonts() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'twentyfifteen-fonts' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_dequeue_google_fonts', 20 );
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  In case anyone else has this problem, and as the other response pointed out, the Enqueue scripts and styles start on line 197 of the parent theme.  Using that and what Nathan provided above allows you to remove a lot of the wp_head items you may not want in your child theme.

Answer (score 5):

Deregister/Dequeue styles is best practice

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_style
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style

But you can use `'style_loader_src'` filter too, to filter out styles with string condition, or other conditions, here is example for google fonts

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', function($href){
if(strpos($href, "//fonts.googleapis.com/") === false) {
return $href;
}
return false;
});
```

Comment: Tried on WP 6 and doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Open theme's `functions.php` and find a function called `twentyfifteen_fonts_url()` - it handles all the fonts stuff. In default file it starts on line 144. Edit it to your needs.

Other options:

1. Use a plugin to control fonts - https://wordpress.org/plugins/typecase/
2. Use a plugin to remove default fonts - https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-open-sans-font-from-wp-core/
3. Use `wp_deregister_style()` function to manually unregister that stylesheet. See [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_style).

As for the IE conditional - check the next function in `functions.php`, called `twentyfifteen_scripts()`. It starts on line 196.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm using a child theme and want to remove those functions from my child theme but keep them in place in the parent theme.  I want to figure this out without a plugin. I know there is a way to dequeue these, just can't get it to work.

Comment: @Peachy the 3rd option will do the job within the child theme. You just need to call the function with right style ID and hook into proper action. See #8 here: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-modify-the-parent-theme-behavior-within-the-child-theme--wp-31006